# How can write the chapter number on the left side of the page

Tags: numbering, chapters

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{%amsfonts, % amsfonts is loaded automatically by amssymb
            amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}

\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext} % load these packages after, not before, amsmath and amssymb

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[head=15pt, vmargin=2in, left=1.5in, right=1in,  
            footskip=2.5cm, % footskip margin
           ]{geometry}
   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[l]{OPOSICIONES}
\fancyfoot[r]{Azahara Carpintero}

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries} % format applied to label+text
{}                                   % label
{1pc}                                % horizontal separation between label and title body
{%
{\huge\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}   % <-- new
    % draw a box around the chapter number:
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            enhanced,flushright upper,
            boxrule=1.4pt,
            colback=white,colframe=black!50!yellow,
            drop fuzzy midday shadow=black!50!yellow,
        width=2.8cm]
        \resizebox{2cm}{!}{\color{gray!80}\thechapter}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    %\Huge % <-- has no effect
    } % before the title body
[] 

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{TEMA}
\setcounter{chapter}{41}
\chapter{Homotecia y semejanza en el plano}
\noindent 42.1 \quad Introducción\\
42.2 \quad  Homotecias del plano\\
42.3 \quad Semejanza en el plano\\
42.4 \quad Aspectos didácticos\\
42.5 \quad Bibliografía
\section{Introducción}
En el tema 37 del presente temario (Relación de semejanza en el plano) se veían los polígonos semejantes, que eran aquéllos en que se establecía una
correspondencia entres sus vértices, de forma que las distancias entre los vértices de un polígono y los correspondientes del otro son proporcionales. 

La generalización de esto es la introducción de aplicaciones del plano en sí mismo, tales que la distancia entre las imágenes de dos puntos es proporcional a la distancia entre dichos puntos. Éstas son las semejanzas del plano.

Comenzaremos con un tipo particular de las mismas, que serán las homotecias, que transforman rectas en rectas paralelas, manteniendo un punto fijo.
\section{Homotecias del plano}
\begin{definition}
\textit{Sea $H: E \rightarrow E$ una aplicación y sea $O \in E$. Se dice que $H$ es una homotecia de centro $O$ si $H(O)=O$ y $\forall r \subset E$ recta: $H(r)$ es una recta paralela a $r$.}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image: I want to put chapter number like this one]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this setup

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries}
{\color{gray!80}\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \newline \Huge\thechapter}
{20pt}{\Huge}[]

%\titlespacing*{<command>}{<left margin>}{<vertical space before the title>}{<vertical space after the title>}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{20pt}
```

you will get

[image: a]

You can use the command `\titlespacing*` to control the space before and after the chapter title.

```
\titlespacing*{<command>}{<left margin>}{<vertical space before the title>}{<vertical space after the title>}
```